# Does this mapping be a curve?

Tags: real-analysis

We know that continuous mapping $\gamma: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}^k$ is called *curve*.

Let's take a look at following picture:
[image]

It means that curve begins from point $\gamma(a)$ and goes to the left by red line and turns back and crossing point $\gamma(a)$ again. Can there be such a case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can just define for $k = 2$ and $a = 0 $, $b = 3$ the following curve
$$
  \gamma(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  (-x,-x), x\in [0,1),
\\
  (x - 2, x - 2), x\in [1, 3].
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Really! Спасибо Вам болшое! :)

Comment: @RaheemNajib: what was your confusion, what did you have doubts such curve would exist?

Comment: Can I talk with you in Russian because I can't explain this in English?

Comment: I thought that you Russian language

Comment: @RaheemNajib давайте, только быстро - комментарии будут удалять :)

Comment: Дорогой Илья! Дело в том, что в книге Рудина для определения длины производят разбиение отрезка. А тут когда тогда $\gamma(A)$ находится в середине я подумал, что ломанная как бы дважды пройдут и определение длины теряет смысл. Надеюсь, что я ясно изложил свои мысли. Было бы интересно послушать Вас.

Comment: So what you think about this?

Comment: @RaheemNajib обычно длину определяют для простой (simple) кривой: той, которая пересечений не имеет. Как раз по той причине, что иначе длина не имеет смысла: можно весь интервал в одну точку отправить.

Comment: But Rudin states that $l[\gamma]=\int \limits_{a}^{b}|\gamma'(t)|dt$ if $\gamma'$ is continuous.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31793/discussion-between-ilya-and-raheem-najib).

Comment: @RaheemNajib: join me in chat (link above)